# How to define object type for gRPC proto in C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I want to define a *proto message* which has a property called ***settings*** that consists in *key-value pairs*.

One of the requirements is that value can be bool, string, numeric & others.

For this I've used **map** structure and **protobuf.Value**

```
 map<string, google.protobuf.Value> settings = 3;
```

But when trying to call the endpoint I need to put a structure like this

[image]

Is there any chance to modify the proto file in order to define messages like this ?

```
"settings": {
   "abc": 4,
   "def": "some_string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a `message` (e.g. `Foo`) to define a `repeated` field (e.g. `settings`).

Then, you can define a `string` field `key` and a `google.protobuf.Value` for `value`:

```protobuf
message Foo {
  repeated Setting settings = 1;
}

message Setting {
  string key = 1;
  google.protobuf.Value value = 2;
}
```

###### Update

Using `repeated Setting` yields a **list** of objects:

```
{
  "settings":[
    {
      "key":"a",
      "value":12
    },
    {
      "key":"b",
      "value":true
    },
    {
      "key":"c",
      "value":"Freddie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `map<string,google.protobuf.Value>` yields an object:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "a:":12,
    "b":true,
    "c":"Freddie"
  }
}
```

`foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/{user}/75747580/protos";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Foo {
  repeated Setting settings = 1;
}

message Setting {
  string key = 1;
  google.protobuf.Value value = 2;
}

message Bar {
  map<string, google.protobuf.Value> settings = 1;
}
```

And:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--go_out=${PWD}/protos \
--go_opt=paths=source_relative \
${PWD}/foo.proto
```

And:
`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    pb "github.com/{user}/75747580/protos"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"
)

func main() {
    {
        foo := &pb.Foo{
            Settings: []*pb.Setting{
                {
                    Key:   "a",
                    Value: structpb.NewNumberValue(12.0),
                },
                {
                    Key:   "b",
                    Value: structpb.NewBoolValue(true),
                },
                {
                    Key:   "c",
                    Value: structpb.NewStringValue("Freddie"),
                },
            },
        }
        log.Printf("%+v", foo)
        b, err := protojson.Marshal(foo)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Println(string(b))
    }
    {

        bar := &pb.Bar{
            Settings: map[string]*structpb.Value{
                "a:": structpb.NewNumberValue(12.0),
                "b":  structpb.NewBoolValue(true),
                "c":  structpb.NewStringValue("Freddie"),
            },
        }
        log.Printf("%+v", bar)
        b, err := protojson.Marshal(bar)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Println(string(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: This structure has the same effect like `map<string, google.protobuf.Value> settings = 3;`

Comment: The two approaches yield different JSON. I'll update my answer with an example.